# How can I extract a YAML block using AWK

Tags: awk, yaml, text-processing

I want to use AWK to extract the '---'-delimited YAML block from a file like the following:

```
---
title: "This is a title"
sourceEditionDate: 1927-01-01
languages:
  - "latin"
tags:
  - poetry
---

Some other text I do not want to extract
```

with the following result:

```
title: "This is a title"
sourceEditionDate: 1927-01-01
languages:
  - "latin"
tags:
  - poetry
```

So far I have tried this approach

```
awk '/---/{p=0};p;/---/{p=1}' file
```

but I still get the entire file including the unwanted last line.

Comment: Would you like to use a YAML syntax aware parser like `yq` for this? - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

Comment: You can't get the output you posted from the input you posted unless you want to add `- "german"` and `- "danish"` from the script.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete those. And thanks for the answer - just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '/---/{f=!f; next} f' file
title: "This is a title"
sourceEditionDate: 1927-01-01
languages:
  - "latin"
tags:
  - poetry
```

Answer (score 0):

And also with `awk` you can get the same result:

```
awk '!/---/' file
title: "This is a title"
sourceEditionDate: 1927-01-01
languages:
  - "latin"
tags:
  - poetry
```

Comment: I expect the OP has other text before/after the block within the `---` lines that they do not want printed, it's just a poor choice of sample input in the question.